# What MPI implementation is needed for YawOptimizationWindRoseParallel()?

Tags: python, installation, mpi, mpi4py, floris

When I want to use the function `YawOptimizationWindRoseParallel()` as is done in the example script called `optimize_yaw_wind_rose_parallel.py`, I need to install `mpi4py`. In the [installation requirements](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#using-pip-or-easy-install) of `mpi4py` they mention that you need 'A working MPI implementation'. Does this mean that I need to install a seperate MPI implementation on top of the `mpi4py` package? And if yes, which one?

Comment: `mpi4py` is a python library (or python bindings) to a MPI implementation (that provides only `C` and `Fortran` bindings), and not a full re-implementation of the MPI standard in python. Consequently, you need to install a MPI library such as Open MPI, MPICH or its derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to install an additional MPI implementation to get `mpi4py` to work with the parallel examples in FLORIS, as Gilles stated. In my experience, Open MPI has worked well with the FLORIS software.